# Converting seconds from specific time on a specific date in R

Tags: r, date, formatting, date-format

If this question has been asked before, please downvote and direct me. I have been looking through SO, but it seems no one has had the need for a non-midnight start time i.e. everyone wants to know how to convert seconds from a specific midnight value.

I'm trying to convert my second values to a data value. What I have are seconds from the time 2017-05-21 22:00.

I tried using the as.POSIXct() function, however it only seem to take Y-m-d into account and disregards if I write h:m after it.

e.g  file$date = as.POSIXct(file$Time,origin = "2017-05-21 22:00") gives me

```
  Time         date
1 0.00         2017-05-22 00:00:00
```

I have found if I use

```
file$Time = file$Time-3600*4

file$date = as.POSIXct(file$Time,origin = "2017-05-22")
```

for some reason gives me the correct output which is of course

```
  Time         date
1 0.00         2017-05-21 22:00:00
```

Any idea on how to do this more elegantly?

Also, if you have a clue on why that gives me the correct output, I'm all ears.

Comment: You can create a date/time of origin date/time and then add seconds offsets to create new date/time.

Comment: @MKR how would you go about that?

Comment: You can try as `as.POSIXct("2017-05-21 22:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + 1` to add `1` second. and `as.POSIXct("2017-05-21 22:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + 100` to add `100` seconds. You dont need any package as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `lubridate`...

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hm("2017-05-21 22:00") + seconds(1.01)
```

So in your case it would be something like

```
file$date <- ymd_hm("2017-05-21 22:00") + seconds(file$Time)
```

Comment: For some reason install.packages("lubridate", dependencies = TRUE) is ok, but library(lubridate) gives me an error, saying "Error in library(lubridate): There is no package called 'Lubridate' ".

Comment: have you restarted the r session? works like a charm in my case with version `1.7.2`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try `as.POSIXct` to convert your starting time and then keep on adding seconds. as:

```
as.POSIXct("2017-05-21 22:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2017-05-21 22:00:00 BST"
 as.POSIXct("2017-05-21 22:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + 1
#[1] "2017-05-21 22:00:01 BST"
 as.POSIXct("2017-05-21 22:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + 100
#[1] "2017-05-21 22:01:40 BST"
 as.POSIXct("2017-05-21 22:00:00", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + 300
#[1] "2017-05-21 22:05:00 BST
```

You can even specify `time-zone` using `tz` parameter as:

```
as.POSIXct("2017-05-21 22:00:00", tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#[1] "2017-05-21 22:00:00 UTC"

as.POSIXct("2017-05-21 22:00:00", tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + 96
#[1] "2017-05-21 22:01:36 UTC"
```